# Repeating result row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables like this

LgDivision

```
  LgDivID LgDivName PBID 

    1      HS        1
    2      HN        1
    3      HE        1
```

PollingBooth

```
   PBID PBName

    1     HomagamaPB
    2     PanagodaPB
```

PollingBoothElection

```
     elecID  PBID 
       1      2
       1      1
       2      2
```

I want to select LgDivName which's PollingBooth is in PollingBoothElection with elecID 1.

Here's what I tried.

```
       SELECT LG.LGDivName,PB.PBName
       FROM LGDivision LG
       INNER JOIN PollingBooth PB ON LG.PBID=PB.PBID
       INNER JOIN PollingBoothElection PBE ON PB.PBID=PB.pbID
       WHERE PB.PBID IN (SELECT pbID FROM PollingBoothElection WHERE   LG.LgDivID=2 AND PBE.elecID=1)
```

Though I get the result I get a repeating row. Why is that?
How to modify this to get a single result always as I enter only 1 LgDivID.

Comment: Your `IN` sub query looks incorrect, the where clause inside the sub query  seems to refer to columns of uncorrelated tables (`LG.LgDivID and PBE.elecID`) that exist outside the sub-query.

Comment: @SoulTrain But I have joined the tables. Will there be a problem then. Coz PollingBooth has many LGDivisions  I'm selecting the polling booth of given LGDivision with givenElection id from PollingBoothElection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ON` clause for the `Inner Join` for PollingBoothElection is using  an incorrect alias, both the columns are from Table `PB` and also you don't need the `IN` clause in this case.

Try this..

```
SELECT *
       FROM LGDivision LG
       INNER JOIN PollingBooth PB ON LG.PBID=PB.PBID
INNER JOIN PollingBoothElection PBE ON PBE.PBID=PB.pbID
       where PBE.elecid=1
and LG.LgDivID=2
```